# Cannot start running on browser the namenode for Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

It is my first time in installing Hadoop on my Linux (Fedora distro) running on VM (using Parallel on my Mac). And I followed every step on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWkbPVNER5k) and including the [textual version](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-13-10) of it.And then when I run it on localhost (or the equivalent value from hostname) in port 50070, I got the following message.

```
...can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:50070
```

When I run the `jps` by the way command I don't have the datanode and namenode unlike at the end of the textual version tutorial which has the following:

[image]

While mine has only the following processes running:

```
6021 NodeManager
3947 SecondaryNameNode
5788 ResourceManager
8941 Jps
```

When I run the `hadoop namenode` command I have some of the following [redacted] error:

```
 Cannot access storage directory /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode
 16/10/11 21:52:45 WARN namenode.FSNamesystem: Encountered exception loading fsimage
 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
```

I tried to access by the way the above mentioned directories and it existed.

Any hint for this newbie? ;-)

Comment: You would need to give read and write access to `/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode` and then you would need to run format command

Comment: Thank you @SMA. I'll give it a try.

Comment: You're right @SMA. I changed to `777` though, because even with `766` permissions it would not work. Could you put your comment into an answer so that I could accept it? Thanks for your answer. GOD bless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to give read and write permission to user with which you are running the services on directory `/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode`.

Once done, you should run format command using `hadoop namenode -format`

Then try to start your services.

Answer (score 0):

delete files /app/hadoop/tmp/*
and try again formatting the namenode and then start-dfs.sh & start-yarn.sh